# How to split a String with null until the end in Java?

Tags: java, split

I have to stringify a simple `Double` array in order to put it in my database (in this case this is the best way I found)

I'm using `StringUtils.join()` to stringify but I have a problem with the splitting because there is a lot of null values at the end of my array (which is expected).

Here is some code example :

```
final String NEEDLE = "_";
Double[] dblArray = new Double[]{2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};
String joined = StringUtils.join(dblArray, NEEDLE);
String[] split = joined.split(NEEDLE); //I will then cast the string to double

Log.d("MyApp", "joined=" + joined);
Log.d("MyApp", "1 - split=" + Arrays.toString(split));
Log.d("MyApp", "2 - StringUtils.split=" + Arrays.toString(StringUtils.split(joined, NEEDLE)));
Log.d("MyApp", "3 - split+xxx=" + Arrays.toString((joined+"xxx").split(NEEDLE)));
Log.d("MyApp", "4 - StringUtils.split+xxx=" + Arrays.toString(StringUtils.split(joined+"xxx", NEEDLE)));
```

And here ARE the results :

> D: joined=2.0_2.0_2.0_0.0_______________________________________________________
>   D: 1 - split=[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
>   D: 2 - StringUtils.split=[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
>  
>   D: 3 - split+xxx=[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , xxx]
>  
>   D: 4 - StringUtils.split+xxx=[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, xxx]

The expected behaviour is the #3, but as you can see, for my split result to contain the null values, I have to add something at the end of the string, which is highly unexpected.

Is there a clean way to split it with null values until the end but without adding dummy value in the end ?

Comment: Maybe do `joined.replaceAll(null, "")` or  `joined.replaceAll(null, "null")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`split(NEEDLE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

You should call [`split(NEEDLE, -1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-):

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.** If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Java 8:

```
String joined = Arrays.stream(dblArray)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Double::toString)
    .collect(joining(","))
```

**Edit**:

If not using Java 8, Guava [Joiner](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) can do this as well.

**Edit 2** ( pre Java 8 and not using third-party lib):

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

for (Double d : dblArray) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(d)) {
        buffer.append(d + ",");
    }
}

String joined = buffer.substring(0, buffer.length() - 1);
```

Comment: ):, Hi, the OP is using android platform, maybe he can't  using stream at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, streams are Java8, and I'm working on Android which still use Java7. But I think there are third-party libs that can copycat streams, I'll give it a try

Comment: @DanChaltiel, See my edit using Guava. Or do you need a core Java solution?

Comment: including guava in android platform is a bad way. the jar is too big.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I think I'll use Lightweight-Stream-API for Android, thanks !

Comment: @DanChaltiel See edit 2. Now you've 3 different ways.